# Get distance from coreMotion data

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I have an arduino controlling an led light strip, and an iphone connected to the arduino via bluetooth. so the number of lights that are turned on correspond to the phones position along an x axis
[image]

Is it possible to use the accelerometer to estimate the distance the phone has traveled. i'm currently polling the accelerometer at 0.01 second intervals. so in 0.5 seconds i'll have an array of 50 values. I believe each value represents the g force at the instance it was measured, so 1.0 = 9.8 meters/second. What would be the formula to take this array and the time interval to calculate the distance? Am i reinventing the wheel here? i feel like arKit has to use some kind of position tracking similar to this. Is there anything in coreMotion that could accomplish this for me.

Obligatory apology for not knowing what i'm doing. also similar questions have been asked before but they are >2 years old and the answer then was its possible but not accurate. i assume it could be more accurate now because arkit wouldn't work without doing something like

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't practical. The problem is drift. You can't tell if the phone is still or moving at a constant velocity, and the accelerometer isn't accurate enough to "zero out" the velocity of the phone. Minor errors in your calculations almost immediately swamp your results and you can't tell if the phone is sitting still or moving at a constant speed.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the second derivative of position.  To start with acceleration you have to integrate twice, which will magnify errors.

To do this you could have two bluetooth sensors (one at each end of the bar) and use triangulation to calculate position.  I haven't done this calculation myself to know all the details of it, but it's the same idea as those bluetooth tags you can have on a bunch of items to help you locate your keys, etc.